# Determining intersection of two HABTM relationships in rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following relationships:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :required_certs, :class_name=>"Certification"
...
end

class User < AR::B
has_and_belongs_to_many :certifications
...
end
```

I'd like to be able to find all users that have the same certifications as an article. So if an article had certs A and B, and User had A, B, C, D, that user would be returned.  Users with just A or just B would not be.  So in essence, something like

```
User.joins(:certifications).where('certifications.id IN (?)', @article.required_certs.collect{|c| c.id})
```

Instead of using the IN operator though, I think I'd have to use AND because I only want users who have ALL of the specified certs.

I'm stumped so any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it, am open to more elegant solutions though!

```
@certs = @article.required_certs.collect{|c| c.id}
User.all(:joins=>:certifications, 
         :group=>User.attributes_for_sql, 
         :select=>'users.*', 
         :conditions => ['certifications.id in (?)', @certs], 
         :having=> "count(*)=#{@certs.length}")
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What is the SQL that was produced by this?

Comment: I think I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779354/rails3-activerecord-fetching-all-records-that-have-a-and-b-through-a-has-many.  Unfortunately your solution ins't making sense to me.  Where does User.attributes_for_sql come from?